# ToString() method not supported

Tags: c#, database, linq-to-sql

I am trying to create a selectlist in c#. My code :

```
       var ceremonies = db.Ceremonies;
        var Ceremonies =
            from c in ceremonies
            select new SelectListItem
            {
                Text = c.Name + "_" + c.Date,
                Value = c.Id.ToString()
            };
```

But here i am getting exception something like `ToString() method not supported`. Whats the problem ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your query is being transformed into SQL - but the call to `ToString` can't be handled properly. Generally the simplest way of fixing this is to effectively split the query into the part that needs to be done in the database, then switch to LINQ to Objects via `AsEnumerable`:

```
var ceremonies = db.Ceremonies
                   .Select(c => new { c.Name, c.Date, c.Id }
                   .AsEnumerable()
                   .Select(c => new SelectListItem {
                               Text = c.Name + "_" + c.Date, 
                               Value = c.Id.ToString()
                           });
```

As an aside, declaring two local variables which vary only by case gives pretty nasty readability.